# Convergence of $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ given $a_{n+m}\leq a_na_m$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

The situation is that $(a_n)$ is a sequence of (strictly) positive real nubmers such that $a_{n+m}\leq a_na_m$ for all $n,m\in\mathbb N$. Then we claim that $(\sqrt[n]{a_n})$ converges. It is easy to see that $a_n^{1/n}\leq a_1$ for all $n$, such that there is a convergent subsequence, but I cannot prove convergence. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Every element of the sequence is bounded, I don't see the problem

Comment: A sequence being bounded does not guarantee convergence of the sequence, just the existence of a convergent subsequence. Consider $(1,0,1,0,\ldots)$. This sequence, though not particularly relevant to the above, is clearly bounded but does not converge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-Taking log both sides and set x(n) = ln(a(n)), then the condition translates to: x(n+m) < x(n) + x(m), and the question now is to show that: the sequence {x(n)/n} converges. We may assume further that the x(n)'s are positive. Here a(n) reads "a sub n".

-The set A ={x(n)/n: n = 1, 2,...} is bounded below by 0 so c = inf(A) exists. 
-Claim: c = lim(x(n)/n)
proof: 
Let epsilon e > 0 be given, there is an m such that: c < x(m)/m < c + e/2, and let n be any natural number greater than m, divide n by m : n = qm + r. So:
x(n) = x(qm + r) < qx(m) + x(r). Hence:
c < x(n)/n < (qx(m) + x(r))/(qm + r) = (x(m)/m)*(qm/(qm+r)) + x(r)/n < c + e/2 + x(r)/n < c + e/2 + M/n, where M = max{x(1),..,x(m-1)}. So choose n > 2M/e then :
c < x(n)/n < c + e/2 + e/2 = c + e. 
Thus x(n)/n --> c.

Comment: I agree you have demonstrated the case where $a_n>1$ for all (or all but finitely many) $n\in\mathbb N$, but why should this case suffice? Thank you.

Comment: After not being lazy and bothering to work some things out, I think you're right in that this argument adapts pretty easily to the case where $c$ is any finite number and for $c=-\infty$.